# How to get accurate value of math function?

Tags: ruby

I have function `<%= (100 / 6000 * 200) %>`, but getting `0` as a result. why? It's real result is `3.333...` How to get it?

Comment: Change the numbers to not be integers.  ex. 100 should be 100.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dividing by integers, not floats. So 100/6000 is 0.16667 which gets <strike>concatenated</strike> truncated to 0. If you divide 100.0/6000.0 you should get the answer you want.

Also, avoid doing math in your views whenever possible.

Comment: Bollocks. Yes I did. Was typing far faster than I was thinking. Thanks @muistooshort